React-select with fixed column table
I am using react-select in my project,
I want to show react-select in a second column of the table. Whenever I made the position as sticky for second column, the dropdown values are getting overlapped by the below select element
I want a table where we first column is checkbox without header, and in second column we need to have react-select without header only, both the columns are sticky, remaining columns need to scroll only.
the dropdown menu should open above over any element

You'll need to provide some code to demonstrate the way this is happening. It could be something as simple as adding a z-index to the checkbox or menu having the issue although this should be done sparingly - https://www.codegram.com/blog/stop-ab-using-z-index/ ), or it could be something else, hence why we need code
